# How to get group names based on group id in azure active directory using graph service client

Tags: c#, .net, azure, azure-active-directory

I want to get a list of group names based on the object id I provide. For example if the id is 5458409c-013f-40d6-8352-522654ae1422 then I want to get the group name of that id which could be 'Marketing' for example. However I keep getting back the wrong group.

Here is the implementation I have so far:

```
 List<AccessGroup> accessGroups = new List<AccessGroup>();

        try
        {
            foreach(var id in group_ids)
            {
                var page = await graph_client.Groups[id].Members.Request().GetAsync();

                string group_name = "";

                group_name = page.OfType<Group>().Select(x => x.DisplayName).FirstOrDefault();

                while (page.NextPageRequest != null)
                {
                    page = await page.NextPageRequest.GetAsync();
                    group_name = page.OfType<Group>().Select(x => x.DisplayName).FirstOrDefault();
                }

                accessGroups.Add(new AccessGroup { Id = id, Name = group_name });
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            Logger.Warning(ex.Message);
            Logger.Warning("Error getting group name from azure security groups");
            throw;
        }
```

Comment: Why are you fetching member details of a group?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like you want to store the first member display name of each page, however `accessGroups.Add(new AccessGroup { Id = id, Name = group_name });` is being called only once. You should add it within the `while` block.

If you want to get the displayName only for the first group member then you may try something like this:

```cs
async Task GetGroupFirstMemberDisplayName()
{

    var members = (await client.Groups.Request().Select(g => g.Id).Expand("members($select=displayName)").GetAsync())
        .Select(g => new { GroupId = g.Id, FirstMemberDisplayName = g.Members.OfType<Group>().FirstOrDefault()?.DisplayName });

    foreach (var item in members)
    {
        Console.WriteLine($"Group {item.GroupId} first member display name: {item?.FirstMemberDisplayName ?? ""}");
    }
}
```

If you just want to get the displayName for all your groups then you can try something like:

```cs
async Task GetGroupDisplayNames()
{

    var names = (await client.Groups.Request().Select(g => g.DisplayName).GetAsync())
        .Select(g => g.DisplayName);

    Console.WriteLine(string.Join(", ", names));
}
```